# React Js - Enviar Datos en formato PDF

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando una contizador automático con react js, llega al carro de compras, sin embargo no tiene pasarela de pagos de bido a que solo envía cotizaciones, el punto es que, el usuario selecciona los productos, la cantidad y otros aspectos; posteriormente se procede a cotizar, y esto, deseo enviarlo en formato PDF. ¿Cómo podría realizarlo?

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [ask] para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira como no puedo comentar te lo escribo desde aqui.
Yo usaría la librería jspdf.

Este sería un ejemplo poniendo texto y luego guardandolo en un archivo pdf con nombre archivo.pdf:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt");
doc.setFont("Arial", "normal");
doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text(`Texto cualquiera`, 20, 30);

doc.save(`archivo.pdf`)
```

Aqui esta la documentación: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo aplicaré en mi app